# Restrict Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have some short `.bat` files used to product lists of filespecs.  For example:

```
C:
cd\Users\garys\Documents
dir *.xlsm /s /b  > %userprofile%\Desktop\xlsm.txt
```

will generate something like:

```
C:\Users\garys\Documents\My Spreadsheets\autocorrect.xlsm
C:\Users\garys\Documents\My Spreadsheets\column id.xlsm
C:\Users\garys\Documents\My Spreadsheets\control word.xlsm
C:\Users\garys\Documents\My Spreadsheets\Data.xlsm
C:\Users\garys\Documents\My Spreadsheets\Dinar.xlsm
```

But if I use:

```
C:
cd\Users\garys\Documents
dir *.xls /s /b  > %userprofile%\Desktop\xls.txt
```

my resulting text file includes files with the ***.xls*** extension as well as files with ***.xlsm*** and **xlsx** extensions.

How can I modify the `.bat` script to ignore the ***.xlsm*** and ***.xlsx*** files ??

Comment: Pipe `DIR` to the `FINDSTR` command and tell it to find XLS at the end of the string using the `/E` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dir *.xls /s /b |findstr /i /e /C:".xls" > %userprofile%\Desktop\xls.txt
```

should provide your data.

output the `dir` command to `findstr` which will find all lines that `/e` end `/c:"this string"` `/i` in a case-insensitive manner

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is that `dir *.xls` also checks the short file names, I think, which is something like `autoco~1.xls` for `autocorrect.xlsm`, for instance.

An alternative way to the additional filter by `findstr` as shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46550668) is to use the [`where` command](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html), which is native to Windows since Vista, I believe, and does a different handling of file names and wild-cards:

```cmd
cd /D "C:\Users\garys\Documents"
where ".:*.xls" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\xls.txt"
```

The prefix `.:` ensures that only matching files in the current directory are returned; otherwise, `where` searches also in the system path directories (type [`path`](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) to display it).

The disadvantage of the `where` command is that it uses also the extensions defined in the `PATHEXT` variable (type `set PATHEXT` to display them), so if there is a file `something.xls.exe` and `PATHEXT` contains `.EXE` in the list (as per default), that file is also returned. A possible work-around is to temporarily delete the variable `PATHEXT`, but you must ensure to restore it immediately afterwards.